# Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False; not hiding application from taskbar

Tags: delphi, pascal

Why setting Application.MainFormOnTaskbar to False is not preventing the application from showing on taskbar?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The name is a bit misleading indeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because that's not what it does.  MainFormOnTaskbar makes it so that the main form shows up as a taskbar button instead of the application itself.  If you want to make an app with *no* presence on the taskbar, see [this article.](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/hide_taskbutton.htm)